# Main class: storm.starter.WordCountTopology. Program will exit

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I need your help in this problem
after installed storm well
what's the useful of using maven ?
i used it and i built storm-starter successfully
but is it create a jar file after building ?

and when i used

```
st@ubuntu:~/storm-0.8.2$ bin/storm jar storm-starter.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology wordcount
```

got this

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   storm.starter.WordCountTopology at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the
>   main class: storm.starter.WordCountTopology. Program will exit.

and when i used this command

```
st@ubuntu:~/storm-0.8.2$ mvn -version
```

got this

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8) Java version: 1.6.0_38 Java home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding:
>   UTF-8 OS name: "linux" version: "3.5.0-23-generic" arch: "i386"
>   Family: "unix"
>   and i'm working on ubnutu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Change directory to bin in terminal, run java -jar storm-starter.jar

Comment: Maven is the build tool which brings all the dependencies and create an archive file. You take a look at pom.XML to understand what happens

Comment: Thanks , but after used this command mvn -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology .it built successful ,but it didn't create a jar file !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to create a jar file, go to the folder that has `pom` file and do:

```
mvn -f m2-pom.xml package
```

then it will create a folder called `target/` where you can actually find your `jar` file

then to start the topology go to the folder where your `pom` file located.

and do something similar to this:

```
storm jar target/storm-starter.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

`jar` file name depends on what you put in `pom` file. In `ubuntu` just type something like `target/st` then press tab and it will show you the options. For the other part you can check the first line in the java file, it should be similar to this:

```
package storm.starter;
```